# mysql script to add query output as input to another query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am trying to write a couple of queries in MySQL that needs to perform the following:
The query here will return all the records that meet caseid=702 with a join from another table.

```
SELECT db.tab1.id as id
  FROM db.tab1 JOIN db.tab2
    ON db.tab1.caseid = db.tab2.padid
 WHERE db.tab1.caseid=702
```

I want to take the output of this query and insert as an array to an UPDATE statement for another table t3.

How do I do that on MySQL? I have read few resources on Cursor or do I have to write stored procedure for it?

Thanks

Comment: Do answers below work for you?

Comment: I have not tried yours yet. But I tried the other one and it worked. I can try yours as well later. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
update table_a set col1 = value1
  where id in (
    SELECT db.tab1.id as id
      FROM db.tab1 JOIN db.tab2
        ON db.tab1.caseid = db.tab2.padid
     WHERE db.tab1.caseid=702
  );
```

Second round: I took the liberty of refactoring you query. I hope it helps:

```
update evou e
  set status = 1234 
  where vid in (
    SELECT vid 
      FROM pay p
      where p.resoncode = 222 
        and p.vid = e.vid
    )
  and e.status=70006
```

Comment: The issue that I have is actually table_a and tab1 is the same. So the output of the inner select needs to be used to update tab1 using the UPDATE call. When I try this query I get the error saying

Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'tab1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Please post the exact SQL you are trying, that gives that error.

Comment: update db.evou 
set status = 1234
where vid in
(SELECT db.evou.vid
  FROM db.evou 
  JOIN db.pay
  ON db.evou.vid = db.pay.vid 
  and db.pay.resoncode=222
  WHERE db.evou.status=70006)

Comment: See the new query. Does it work for you? It doesn't show any error when I try it.

Comment: Worked..Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Update from the join like this:

```
   update a set a.yourcolumn=a.newcolumnvalue 
     from t3 a join (
     SELECT db.tab1.id as id
      FROM db.tab1 JOIN db.tab2
        ON db.tab1.caseid = db.tab2.padid
     WHERE db.tab1.caseid=702)b
     on a.id=b.id
```

Comment: No need for the subquery, just join with `tab1` and `tab2` in the UPDATE

Comment: Although MySQL should just translate this to the same thing.